# How can I pass dynamically generated CSS to Sass?

Tags: sass

I have a chunk of dynamically generated CSS I'd like to include in a Sass stylesheet being rendered via `sass.renderSync`. How can I provide the CSS to Sass in such a way that it is then emitted in the output? Due to how Sass is being called, I can't write any modifications to disk, so I'm unable to add the CSS to the main Sass file or emit a new Sass file to be included.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

*app.js*

```js
const css = ".main { font-family: sans-serif; }";
const generatedCss = sass.renderSync({ file: "styles/index.scss" });
```

*styles/index.scss*

```
body { margin: 0; }
// I want to include `css` here
```

Answer (score 0):

you could append the dynamic css to the file that your passing in before doing `sass.renderSync`

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const sass = require('node-sass')

const css = '.main { font-family: sans-serif; }'
fs.appendFile('styles/index.scss', css, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
  const generatedCss = sass.renderSync({ file: "styles/index.scss" });
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but editing the original file on disk isn't an option. I've updated the post to reflect this.